# Selenium get stuck while connecting to Firefox

Tags: django, firefox, ubuntu, selenium, python-3.x

I'm working on a website with Python 3 and Django 1.6. I wanted to create a view, which renders a particular element from my site to a png. Therefore I use Selenium to remote control Firefox to get a specific page from my webserver and the fetching a screenshot for the response. The following code is written for this purpose:

```
def do_get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
    from selenium import webdriver
    import base64

    display = Display(visible=0, size=(200, 100))
    display.start()

    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://www.google.com')
    response = base64.b64decode(browser.get_screenshot_as_base64())
    browser.quit()

    display.stop()

    return HttpResponse(content=response, mimetype='image/png')
```

The problem is, that if I'm running the code via the python3 console directly as root everything is working fine. But my apache works with a different user without root permissions. When I try to execute the code with this user, the code is stuck in the line

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

It seems that Selenium can't connect to Firefox, when I interrupt the exection following traceback occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 6, in <module>
   browser = webdriver.Firefox()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
   self.binary, timeout),
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 47, in __init__
   self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 60, in launch_browser
   self._start_from_profile_path(self.profile.path)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 83, in _start_from_profile_path
   env=self._firefox_env).communicate()
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 936, in communicate
   stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 487, in _eintr_retry_call
   return func(*args)
```

It seems to be a user permission issue, therefore I changed the owner of the installed firefox to my apache user. I can run firefox from the console with this user, but with the webserver the problem persists. My server is running a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS instance.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the latest version of Firefox? I upgraded to version 32 this morning and the webdriver plugin is no longer supported.

Mozilla support [suggests](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/install-older-version-of-firefox) using Chrome instead of downgrading :-(

Comment: After stumbling over this issue, I've downgraded FF to version 30, which is basically working. I already gave Chrome a short try, but it is more difficult to build up the connection from selenium to Chrome than FF. Apart from that it seems to be a permission issue, I'm close to a workaround, hopefully I can get it running. Thanks for your answer!